# Unit test fail - is not a function

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have angular component where I have something like this:

```
import { SomeInterface } from '../interfaces';

.....

export class SomeComponent implement OnInit, SomeInterface {

valueUpdated(value: string) {
    ....
    if(value.length === 6) {
       this.enterValue = value;
       this.submit();
    }
}

submit() {
    (this as SomeInterface).triggerSomething(true);
    .....some other things
}
```

.

```
export interface SomeInterface {
    ....
    triggerSometing(value: boolean);
}
```

.

```
it('should call valueUpdated', () => {
    component.valueUpdated('123456');
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const submitSpy = spyOn(component, 'submit' as any);
    
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(submitSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

And then in unit test when I go throw this function unit test fail: this.triggerSomething is not a function.

How can I fix it, maybe mock this interface in unit test but I do not know how exactly to do that.

Comment: Hi! Please add more details to your question: your unit test code and your Angular component code would be both handy to provide an answer. Also, is your Angular component implementing that interface? We can see it when you share the code.

Comment: Hi, I add more details. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The interface `SomeInterface` is there as a contract to ensure that whoever implements it, implements it correctly.

This means that if `SomeComponent` implements it, it should have a `triggerSomething` method.

When you do:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit, SomeInterface {
```

Does the TypeScript compiler complain? It should be.

Also, the main issue is this:

```
(this as SomeInterface).triggerSomething(true);
```

We are casting `this` to `SomeInterface` and then we call `triggerSomething` where it does not exist.

To fix it quickly, you can do:

```
submit() {
    this.triggerSomething(true);
    .....some other things
}

triggerSomething(value: boolean) {
  // do nothing - just make the interface happy
}
```

Comment: component works fine no compiler error. I just need fix the unit test.

Comment: The problem is `(this as SomeInterface)`. Change this to `this.triggerSomething(true);` and most likely you will see errors. This is the main issue. `triggerSomething` does not exist in this component.